# Best way to store big data in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an idea about app in Swift. I will have to store huge amounts of text (essays) and have that sorted in table view by alphabetical order. I am not sure what is the best to store those essays and how to do it. Core data? userdefaults?

Comment: @Wain Has to be stored locally :/

Comment: **NOT** NSUserDefaults. Whenever you have *huge* amount of data you want to do operations of any kind other than reading on, for example sorting - then NSUserDefaults is pretty much worst choice you can go with.

Comment: @luk2302 Got it. Thanks. Any idea what to do with the problem?

Comment: You may want to look into storing Document data in your case, otherwise Core Data.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Will do, thank you. Is there any way to put all the essays in one text file and get it from there?

Comment: You can absolutely do that. You should probably look into file reading and writing, there's a ton of ways to approach this and it really deals with the architect of your app. I would also advice you to take a look into a few tutorials regarding persistent storage prior to engaging.

Comment: Great :) Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to store big data locally is Sqlite or Core Data which is an interface over Sqlite, but has some advantages like visual objects (entities + relationships), object graph management, etc. Don't save big data in NSUserDefaults because it's slow and it makes hard to maintain complex objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just advice, if you want to store big data I would recommend Realm swift database. As for me it's much better in this way than CoreData as it can be simply used with multithreading(CoreData is much more harder as you need to manage it on your own). And if you are saving really huge amount of data I think it would be better to perform this action on background just to prevent lagging in programs main thread. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Realm : Realm scalability is an important feature. Realm can handle many users and a significant volume of data. Realm includes concise and well-written documentation for developers, which translates into faster development processes.

coreData : Core Data is a persistence framework, not a database. The framework includes built-in capabilities that reduce code developers write by 70 percent.